# Why wont my Assembly Code run (.asm, VB Desktop 2013, C++)

Tags: visual-studio-2013

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
bigEndian byte 12h,34h,56h,78h
littleEndian dword ?

.code
main proc
mov  ah,byte ptr bigEndian              ; high byte
mov  al,byte ptr bigEndian+1            ; 2nd byte
mov  word ptr littleEndian+2,ax         ; high word
mov  ah,byte ptr bigEndian+2            ; 3rd byte
mov  al,byte ptr bigEndian+3            ; 4th byte  
mov  word ptr littleEndian,ax           ; low word

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

First time using VS2013 and I cannot figure out why this will not run. It tells me in the bottom console 1 fail and a pop-up states "Unable to start program"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error page, when that error pop-up appears it means that you have not set-up Visual Studio correctly. In this case, the Kip Irvine was no downloaded and that there was no space in the Handlers section in setup.